# could not respond to event didChangeData in state rootState.loaded.created.uncommitted

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting this error when creating a record as well as loading fixtures
through the adapter.  It works okay when I put the create method function in a
timer.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lewang/tUtfm/6/).

Any ideas?

Comment: In your fiddle, the record you create is given the same id as a fixtured record. Is it intended?

Comment: +1 with @StéphaneBlond. It does not make sense to have two records with the same id. For example giving an id of 3 to the record you want to create, makes the fiddle work